# Installing Qt 5.1.1 and qwt 6.1.0 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: qt, ubuntu-12.04, qwt

I've recently came to linux from a 1 year Windows run in Qt so I don't know how this works exactly and couldn't find any thing decent. So here it is :

As is obvious from the title I'm trying to install Qt 5.1.1 and Qwt 6.1.0 in Ubuntu 12.04. I have written a project with the same versions in Windows and now I want to run the project in Linux. The problem is I don't know If I'm doing the installing process right!

I installed Qt 5.1.1 in `/opt/qt5.1.1` and compiled Qwt 6.1.0 to `/usr/local`. I copied the files in include, lib, plugin/designer to the related folders in qt 5.1.1. After this the plugin is fine and I can see the .h files when I type include but when I want to run my project I get the error *undefined reference to ...* for every method or attribute of Qwt library used!

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: (If you really put a space in that directory name, I urge you to reconsider. Avoid spaces in directory and file names, you're likely to get all kinds of headaches from build scripts if you don't.) As for your question, did you add the Qwt libraries to the linker flags? And why did you copy stuff from Qwt to the Qt intall location? (Don't do that either.)

Comment: @Mat: As for the spaces issue, you're right, that was a miss type on the post which I edited. I didn't add qwt libraries to linker flags, how can I do that? I copied them because I wasn't clear on what to do **after** I compiled qwt and there was no connection between QT and qwt. This is exactly where I need help :(

Comment: http://qwt.sourceforge.net/qwtinstall.html#RUNAPP

Comment: @Mat: Thank you for the link! I'm not sure though, should set I all three of the flags to the include directory of qwt? I added `QMAKE_LFLAGS_PATH += /usr/local/qwt-6.1.0/include` to the .pro filebut I got an error. What am I doing wrong now?

Comment: @Mat: Never mind, I ran `qmake -set QMAKEFEATURES ${QWT_ROOT}/features` and I got it working for now , Thank you Mat :) Sorry for the newbie question